# Can't transfer a file with a binary transfer with a FTP client

Tags: java, ftp

Have this FTP client where I transfer files with byte array. In the console it says Successfully transferred but it doesn't transfer anything and I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ftp.ftp.connect(ftp.java:110)
at ftp.test.main(test.java:12)
```

I want files to be tranferred to this filepath: c:/Users/username/Desktop/FTP

This is my program:

```
package ftp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ftp
{
public synchronized void connect(String host, int port, String user,
        String pass) throws IOException {
    Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
    //  if (socket != null) {
    //     throw new IOException("SimpleFTP is already connected. Disconnect first.");
    //   }
    //  socket = new Socket(host, port);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));


    String response = reader.readLine();

    if (!response.startsWith("220-")) {
        throw new IOException(
                "FTP modtog et ukendt svar, da den blev forbundet til FTP server: "
                        + response);
    } else {System.out.println("1:"+response);
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("1:"+response);
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("1:"+response);


    }
    writer.write("user geek"+"\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("2"+response);
    // response = reader.readLine();
    /*  if (!response.startsWith("331 ")) {
          throw new IOException(
              "SimpleFTP received an unknown response after sending the user: "
                  + response);
        }
        else {*/
    writer.write("PASS hello" +"\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("3"+response);
    //}


    //response = reader.readLine();
    /*if (!response.startsWith("230 ")) {
          throw new IOException(
              "SimpleFTP was unable to log in with the supplied password: "
                  + response);
        }
        else {*/
    //System.out.println("4"+response);
    //}

    writer.write("pasv"+"\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("5"+response );
    String [] r=response.trim().split(",");

    String reg=r[4];
    String add= r[5].replace(")", "");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(reg);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(add);

    int port1 = m*256+a;
    System.out.println(port1);
    Socket datasocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port1);
    writer.write("type A\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("6"+response);
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(datasocket.getInputStream()));


    writer.write("LIST\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response= reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("7"+response);


    String text;
    while((text =reader2.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(text);

        writer.write("RETR\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        response= reader.readLine();
        System.out.println("8"+response);

        Socket filsocket = new Socket ("localhost", port1);
        InputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
        try {
            is = filsocket.getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");

            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) >= 0) {
                fos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
            }
        } finally {
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            filsocket.close();
        }

    }


}       

}
```

Output:

```
1:220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.50 beta
1:220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
1:220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
2331 Password required for geek
3230 Logged on
5227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,219,100)
6200 Type set to A
7150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp              0 Apr 14 20:18 abc.txt
8226 Successfully transferred "/"
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:   connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ftp.ftp.connect(ftp.java:112)
at ftp.test.main(test.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. There are a number of issues to fix here. First, every time you need to get data over the data channel (using that arbitrary high port you're calculating from the passive response), you need to issue another PASV command and open a new socket using that new port.

Try this, code, starting with the LIST command:

```
writer.write("LIST\r\n");
writer.flush();
response = reader.readLine();
System.out.println("7" + response);

List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
String text;
while ((text = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
    String filename = parseFilename(text);
    files.add(filename);
}
reader2.close();
datasocket.close();
reader.readLine();

for (String file : files) {
    int passivePort = getPort(reader, writer);
    writer.write("RETR test.txt\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    System.out.println(response);
     byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    // try-with-resources
    try (Socket filesocket = new Socket("localhost", passivePort);
         InputStream is = filesocket.getInputStream();
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\" + file)) {
         int count;
         while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) >= 0) {
             fos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
         }
    }
}
```

getPort then, of course, looks like this:

```
private int getPort(BufferedReader reader, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException {
    String response;
    writer.write("PASV" + "\r\n");
    writer.flush();
    response = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("5" + response);
    String[] r = response.trim().split(",");

    String reg = r[4];
    String add = r[5].replace(")", "");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(reg);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(add);

    return m * 256 + a;
}
```

I'll let you write parseFilename; that's just a matter of pulling the filename from the raw listing returned by the server.

This code should do the trick for you, and worked for me against a local Apache FTP server. Since you're using Filezilla, you may need to read in an extra line somewhere if they're returning more data than my server was -- but otherwise this could should work for you.

Comment: Ok, found another issue... make sure you have the filename with the RETR command. Should look like this:  

     writer.write("RETR abc.txt\r\n");  

Once that's done, you want to stick with the first localhost socket to read in the file.

Comment: But then I only transfer abc.txt not any file. I want to transfer any file not only abc.txt

Comment: I get an error on this: `Socket filsocket = new Socket ("localhost", port1);`

Comment: Try closing the 'datasocket' Socket after it gets the list of files. You won't be able to init filsocket while the other socket is still open.

Comment: As for transferring all files: FTP doesn't really work that way. Command-line clients usually support the 'MGET' command, but the client still has to read the list of files and do an individual RETR command for each file. Once you have this working, you'll need to parse the list of files in the folder and do an individual RETR for each file.

Comment: It dosen't help that I close the socket

Comment: Updated my comment above. You do still need to use one RETR command per file, but it's fairly easy to loop through the files as you'll see in the code I added.

Comment: Can't I use this while loop:                                                                    `String text; while((text =reader2.readLine())!=null){       System.out.println(text);` but change the reader?

Comment: How do you close datasocket when it's not defined?

Comment: How do I make the parseFilename method? Now it says `7503 Bad sequence of commands.` in console

Comment: The first code snippet above was just from the LIST command; you still want to keep the code you have above that -- you shouldn't need to change code before that.

For parseFilename, just have it return 'abc.txt' for now since you know that file exists -- just to see if everything else is working. Then you can move on to parsing the filename from the individual string.

Comment: Then I get this output `Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: etc.` the error occurs on the line with the filesocket

Comment: and if I change test.txt to abc.txt it gives an error on this `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\temp\\" + file))` and says that the written filepath wasn't found

Comment: `3230 Logged on
5227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,232,18)
6200 Type set to A
7150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
5227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,232,20)
150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"`

Comment: I get this output. In the file changes but I get his out it doesn't show which files there are in the folder anymore

Comment: Maybe you don't have a c:\temp directory? Change that to whatever folder you want to save in. If it's getting that far, then it's at least able to create the socket to read the file; you must be close...

Comment: Have changed the directory but it it gives the output I wrote. It uploades as the file changes (have at the date in properties)